# django forms and processing meta data for objects

Tags: django, validation, hidden, django-forms

Say i have this model:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True) #name of job
    start = models.TimeField() #start time of job
    end = models.TimeField() #end time of job
    days = models.ManyToManyField(Day) #week days the job should be started on
```

Say i also have a function that takes the start, end, and days fields and hashes out a bitarray of 35,040 bits ('111100011...').  (each bit is actually a 15-minute chunk, there are 35040 chunks in a year)

I dont necessarily expect the user to input all those bits, i want to do that for them behind the scenes.  However, how do i "attach" this bit data to the Job object without requiring the user to enter it on my modelForm and without trying to validate it's data?

Answer (score 0):

Add an optional field to your model (it will be excluded from Form validation):

```
hash = models.CharField(max_length=.., Null=true, Blank=true)
```

then generate it when saving to the database (by overriding model's save method):

```
def save(self):
    self.hash = calc(...)
    super(MyModel, self).save()
```